# Necessary conditions for unique convergence of a sequence of random variables.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Suppose that I have a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$, where $X_i \in R$ for all $i=1,...,n$, for some space $R$. Furthermore, suppose I have a function $S$ with arguments in $R$ such that $S \geq 0$, and $S(x) = 0$ is uniquely determined when $x = 0$.

Then if for all $\epsilon >0$,

$$P\{S(X_n) > \epsilon\} \rightarrow 0,$$

as $n\rightarrow \infty$, that is, $S(X_n)\xrightarrow{p} 0$, then under what conditions does this imply that $X_n \xrightarrow{p} 0$?

EDIT: My intuition suggests that all we need is that $S$ is continuous in $X$ when $R$ is a metric space, and that $S(x)= 0$ is uniquely determined by $x=0$ only, but I can't seem to prove it.

EDIT #2: Suppose that $S$ is convex and has a unique minimum at $S(0) = 0$, first answer has pointed out a flaw in my initial question.

Answer (score 1):

What about $X_n = n$ a.s., and $S\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_+$ defined by $$S(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^4+1}$$?

You will get $S(X_n) \to 0$ a.s., but clearly not what you want for $(X_n)_n$. Yet $S\geq 0$ is continuous and cancels only at $0$.

---

It looks like a sufficient condition for what you want is that $S$ be continuous and strictly monotone with $S(0)=0$, as then $$\mathbb{P}\{S(X_n)>\varepsilon\} = \mathbb{P}\{X_n>S^{-1}(\varepsilon)\}$$ (continuity is probably not even needed in that case). Note that in the above counterexample, $S$ is not monotone/injective.

Comment: Good one, maybe I should add another condition as that wasn't a function I would have considered - I wonder if we can make the condition more general, the function $S$ that you have described to me seems to be bi-modal and asymptotically decays to $0$ at either $\pm \infty$, what about if we had a function $S$ that was uni-modal, for example say a convex function, where the limit of $S$ in neither positive or negative direction is $0$?

Comment: @user61038 Sorry if it's trivial, but e.g. assuming $S$ is twice differentiable, doesn't your new condition imply that $S$ is monotone increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and monotone decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$, which basically immediately implies the result? (as then $\{S(X_n > \varepsilon\} = \{X_n < S_1^{-1}(\varepsilon)\}\cup  \{X_n > S_2^{-1}(\varepsilon)\}$ where $S_1^{-1},S_2^{-1}$ are the two "one-sided inverses.")

Comment: Yes, in the case it's correct when $R =\mathbb{R}$, but I think I'm trying to find a more formal formulation when $R = \mathbb{R^d}$, for $d >1$, or even, if $R = L_2(\mathbb{R})$